# Generated random string isn't random when called more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to create a randomly generated string of words, which works fine unless I call it multiple times in a row. This is on a WebForms page that and the list of words comes from a file.

I suspect I'm not understanding something with out C# or possibly ASP.NET works in this case, can someone explain why this is happening and how to approach a fix?

Here is the method

```
public string GeneratePhrase()
{
    // get dictionary file
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/libs/words.txt"));

    Random rand = new Random();
    int r1 = rand.Next(data.Count());
    int r2 = rand.Next(data.Count());
    int r3 = rand.Next(data.Count());

    string p1 = data.ElementAt(r1).ToLower();
    string p2 = data.ElementAt(r2).ToLower();
    string p3 = data.ElementAt(r3).ToLower();

    string ret = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", p1, p2, p3);
    return ret;
}
```

If I call this once during a `PostBack`, it's fine and always creates a random combination of words. However if I use this more than once during a *PostBack*, it simply repeats the same random string from each call.

```
string s1 = this.GeneratePhrase();
string s2 = this.GeneratePhrase();
string s3 = this.GeneratePhrase();
Response.Write(s1);
Response.Write(s2);
Response.Write(s3);
```

output

```
tirefriendhotdog
tirefriendhotdog
tirefriendhotdog
```

Any reason on why this may happen?

Comment: Call `Random rand = new Random();` only once.  Try moving that line outside of that scope.

Comment: I suspect this is all taking place *very* quickly and the three different `Random` objects have the same exact seed values.

Comment: I like that your problem is my solution, I was having the exact opposite problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Random rand = new Random();` uses the current time as a seed value, so calling it multiple times in quick succession will give you the same random sequences.  You can:

- create a single `Random` object that is used for all requests
- seed it with a different pseudo-random number like `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()`
- Use a different random number generator that is not time-dependent.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you, it works well now that I understand it.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has this to say about the parameterless constructor for `Random`:

> The `Random()` constructor uses the system clock to provide a seed value. This is the most common way of instantiating the random number generator.

When you create several new instances of `Random` in short succession, they may end up with the same seed, and so produce the same sequence.

To get proper (pseudo)randomness, it is best to have only a single instance of `Random` per thread in you application.